# Blend c++ with python or transfer data between

Tags: python, c++, c

I checked "Python Programming/[Extending with C++](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Extending_with_C%2B%2B)", "Python Programming/[Extending with C](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Extending_with_C)", and boost with this [github][github.com/TNG/boost-python-examples]. but for c file without main() the eclipse say
 `undefined reference to main` 
and boost file after add main() and run with "python test.py" in terminal say

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hello.py", line 3, in <module>
    import hello
  File "/home/ahrovan/workspace/Test_py/src/hello.py", line 4, in <module>
    print (hello.greet())
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'greet'
```